# how to set value to a null object in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have recently added new field to my table and previous rows will have null value for that field until someone update it.so i tried updating the value by using `myobject.findById(1).mynewfield = "data"`but its raising an exception saying

> Cannot set property 'mynewfield' on null object

i know mynewfield is null for the fetched object but
 does this mean i cant set some value to an object which was null and if so what should i use to change its value ?
here is my code

Comment: findById should rarely ever be used only in scenarios where you want to findByIdAndSomeState. In your case it should be def aa= myObject.get(0)?.fieldName  and ? will take care of it throwing a null error then its up to you to check aa has a value so if (aa) { then do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message rather tells that `myobject.findById(1)` is null. Do you have `myobject` domain class and do you have instance of it with id = 1?

Double check it.

Comment: yea ur right . i tried it with debugger and saw that the object is null.thanks